# jquery hide/show or condiiton failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Is there anything wrong with the jQuery/JS below? I have an input field `aAmt` which on change calls below. `${dAmt} = "10000"` from DB. It basically converts the number to $ format(eg.. 23 to $23.00) and focuses the value to the input field. Issue is the if loop (`if(aAmt >= a_amount)...`) fails.

Even if the condition fails it goes to if loops and shows the `div` which should not happen. I don't see any error in developers console.

```
$('#aAmt').change(function() {
    var aAmt = $("#aAmt").val();
    var a_amount = "${dAmt}";           
    curFormat(aAmt);        
    if(aAmt >= a_amount)    
    {       
        $("#dsDiv").show();     
    }else{
        $("#dsDiv").hide();
    }   

});

function curFormat(aAmt)
{
    var nAmt = Number(aAmt.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var fAmt = '$' + nAmt.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");    
    document.getElementById("aAmt").value = fAmt;
}
```

Comment: you're comparing currency values as strings, which will never work. `'$9' > '$10'` is TRUE, because `9` is a "bigger" character than "1". String comparisons of numbers are never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to convert a_amount to an int, to be sure to compare two integers together:

```
var a_amount = parseInt("${dAmt}");
```